# Best way to clean moldy fermentation bucket

Tags: sanitation, bucket, mold

I've just had a major house move. During the move, I noticed my fermentation bucket had developed mold. Quite large mounds (to me anyway) of perhaps 0.25in diameter, in the corner of the base. Clearly I didn't do a good job of cleaning it last time I used it.

So far I've only rinsed with high pressure water - basically to remove the odour for the move. How should I best kill and clean this stuff ready for brewing? Is regular StarSan sufficient?  Of course chlorine bleach would really clean it but it would leave a bad taste. Perhaps something else?
Or perhaps I should just replace the bucket at chalk it up to "remember to clean the bucket properly".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StarSan is a sanitizer, not a cleaner.  I'd use Craftmeister alkaline cleaner.  Amazing stuff and makes PBW look weak.  Or just buy a new bucket.

Comment: Both seem good answers, but Craftmeister is new to me, so I'll try that. I've moved to a new town and will be investigating the local brew shop in a few weeks for my next brew, and see if they have it.

Comment: My co author, Drew Beechum, and I did a comparison review between Craftmeister and PBW.  You can read it here....http://www.experimentalbrew.com/blogs/drew/craftmeister-cleaners-picturing-carboy-test

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what bucket you use, it might just be easier to buy a new one. :)

Otherwise, get an unscented soap and wash properly. Rinse, wash again, just to make sure. Rinse well. And verify that you got everything.

You can now use StarSan to sanitize your fermenter. after it has been cleaned.